# Can SLLN be applied to $Y=\frac {1 } {k} \sum _{n=1 } ^ {k} Z _n 2^{-n } $, where $Z _n $ are iid?

Tags: probability-theory

Can the strong law of lagre numbers be applied to conclude convergence of sum $\frac {1 } {k} \sum _{n=1 } ^ {k} Z _n 2^{-n } $, where $Z _n $ are iid??

I can see that every partial sum can be written as number $0,Z _1Z _2Z _3 ...Z _n $ in the base 2.

And in my special case I have that $Z _n $ takes the value $1$ with probability $2/3 $ and the value $0 $ with probability $1/3 $, so that two thirds of the numbers should be ones and on therd should be zeroes in the base 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume your sum is meant to be $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k} Z_k$?  But in your case $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} Z_n$ already converges almost surely (to a finite limit) so if you multiply by $\frac{1}{n}$ the result will converge almost surely to 0.

Comment: OP: I think you have your phrasing backwards.  Rather, I think you mean to say that $Z_n$ takes the value $1$ with probability $2/3$ and the value $0$ with probability $1/3$.

Comment: Yes, you are both correct!

Comment: @NateEldredge It's not even an almost-surely; since the sum is explicitly bounded between $0$ and $1$, then the product of $\frac1n$ with the sum must necessarily converge to 0 (since it's bounded from above by $\frac1n$).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: To be extremely pedantic, we haven't excluded the possibility that $Z_n$ takes some other value (say $2^n$), but with probability 0.